# How set TextView value with sum of numeric ListView loaded from database

Tags: java, android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `Fragment` composed by a `ListView` and a `TextView`. ListView contains  several `TextView` with numeric values loaded from database via custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` and `CursorLoader`. So these values are static after displayed. I want to sum values and show directly the total in the separate TextView.
How can i do it? I mean from user point of view the list and the total must be displayed at the same time. I can use an additional loader for getting the total separately but I want to avoid this. So in which point should I put sum logic?

I have a query like this where each row will populate an item for listView:

```
SELECT group_name, group_amount FROM notes;
```

I don't want to execute a separate query as below to calculate the total amount, i would like to get it safely from GUI if possible

```
SELECT sum(group_amount) FROM notes;
```

Here it is my code:

FRAGMENT onCreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monthly_report, container, false);
        ListView listCosts = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_costs);
        costsAdapter = new VehReportAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    com.vortexalex.vehnotes.R.layout.monthly_report_single_item, null,
                    VehReportAdapter.fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        listCosts.setAdapter(costsAdapter);
}
```

FRAGMENT onActivityCreated

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(VehTabsUtil.REPORT_COSTS_LOADER_ID, null, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this); 
}
```

FRAGMENT onLoaderFinished

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {  
    costsAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

ADAPTER bindView (Adapter `extends SimpleCursorAdapter`)

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    Integer dbAmount = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountingContract.Report.COLUMN_NAME_GROUP_AMOUNT));
    String amount = NumberUtil.formatAmount(dbAmount);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(com.vortexalex.vehnotes.R.id.report_item_amount)).setText(amount);
```

}

FRAGMENT LAYOUT montly_report.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_costs"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="0dip"
               android:layout_weight="2"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/costs_sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="6dip"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What value? Total number of items in the list?

Comment: @Apurva no, they represent amounts

Comment: I edited my post with new details about SQL queries

Comment: post your database helper code as well

Comment: I don't think it's useful to post helper code which is simple. The 'query' part works well. I just implemented the `Loader.loadOnBackground` method which calls the helper and returns a `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have numbers in your listview, and you'd like the sum of every value in your listview.

To achieve this loop over every value in your list view, convert the value from `String` to `int` using `Integer.parseInt(String str)`, add them all up and convert the resulting `int` back to a `String` using `Integer.toString(int i)`, and insert the resulting `String` in your text view with `yourTextView.setText(resultString)`.

Comment: Type conversion is just very small percentage of the effort. How I iterate over list view? And above all WHERE... in which component? Adapter or Fragment? Consider that after the sum I must be able to access the sum TextView

Comment: It's very trivial iterating over a list view simply iterate over the adapter of the list view. Where to put it is up to you, as I don't know when you want to display the value. The textview can be made a field for easy reference.

Comment: I can think of a couple of suitable places to iterate, though. You could refresh values from your activities `onStart()` if you'd like it refreshed every time your activity is started. You can also override `notifyDataSetChanged()`, to refresh the sum when the values in the list view change (HINT, HINT, I'D USE THE SECOND OPTION)